# How to solve "Login Only" rejection when applying to Google AdSense

Tags: google-adsense, authentication, google-adsense-policies

Recently, a site of mine was rejected due to "Login Only":

> Login Only: During our review of your website, we found that the majority
>   of pages on your site are behind a login, or there is restricted access.
>   Please note that we will not approve applications for login-protected
>   pages, as we are not able to review their content for acceptance into the
>   program.

Although the site does require login to send content, it doesn't require any to view any page. How do I tell the Googlebot or whatever is used to crawl pages to AdSense that all the content is publicly available but registration is needed to post?

**Current robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /moderation/
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /
```

Comment: can you link to the website?

Comment: @YardenST I'm afraid not. Can you help me with the provided information?

Comment: that's a situation! Can you change the way pages are accessed? Maybe you are using some cookies or something that is blocking google crawlers from seeing the pages as public?

Comment: @Renan Do you have any mechanism in your website, that prevent bots from accessing the site?

Comment: @YardenST I do have some restrictions in robots.txt. I added it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I resolved it.

Google sends crawler to visit your site. It´s automatic robot control, not human control. Your rejection is also automatic from this crawler.

If you want see what crawler really gets when he visits your site, you must using some text web browser like [Lynx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29). After using this browser, I saw what my problem was:

- The crawler need to see only clean links. If you have some other element nested inside the `A` element (like a `span`) the crawler won´t see it as a link. For the crawler, I had only one clean link and it was a link to login page.
- The crawler doesn't support content filled in with AJAX.

Take a look to your page with Lynx browser to find the reason why you get rejection.