# AdSense application rejected for "login only" content and difficult navigation, but content is public in a standard blog format

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I'm maintaining a blog that I hope to get accepted into the Adsense Program. It was rejected due to the following reasons:

Login Only: During our review of your website, we found that the majority of pages on your site are behind a login, or there is restricted access. Please note that we will not approve applications for login-protected pages, as we are not able to review their content for acceptance into the program.

Difficult site navigation: During our review of your website, we found your site difficult to navigate. Potential navigation issues include: redirects, pages behind a login or restricted access, broken links, excessive pop-ups, dialers, and pages under construction or not yet launched.

I think both of them don't make sense. None of my contents are for login only, and I don't really see that my site is particularly difficult to navigate. Am I missing anything obvious? My address is:
http://koreanforinternauts.blogspot.ca/

Comment: I'm not sure why those reasons would be used.    You need 50 pages (blog posts) to qualify for AdSense.   Right now you have only 26.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller then Adsense will email that, "you've not quality/enough content", but here they said "it's required login to see content", it means their [automatic bot does not see the blog content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/47643/58259). I will suggest to change your blogger template(default will be great) and then re-apply, because may be your current template is AJAX based, which adsense crawler/bot can't crawl it.

Comment: @Goyllo Yes, I had tried changing blogger template to one of the default ones and re-applying, but it was still rejected for the same reasons (Login only + Difficult site navigation). Everyone I talked to seem to think that there are no major issues with my website, so I'm pretty confused. I have nearly 60 quality posts too...

Comment: I don't think you'll get your answer here, because your site is fine, and the problem is from adsense side. Just go to [adsense help forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/adsense) and write their mistake. If you don't get proper answer make other thread after some time. Only adsense team can help you.